# Get DBa value using gravity sound meter with ADC module with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I need help to get actual value from gravity sound meter with raspberry pi.

I have a python program to get those details

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import time
from DFRobot_ADS1115 import ADS1115
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_6_144V        = 0x00 # 6.144V range = Gain 2/3
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_4_096V        = 0x02 # 4.096V range = Gain 1
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_2_048V        = 0x04 # 2.048V range = Gain 2 (default)
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_1_024V        = 0x06 # 1.024V range = Gain 4
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_0_512V        = 0x08 # 0.512V range = Gain 8
ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_0_256V        = 0x0A # 0.256V range = Gain 16
ads1115 = ADS1115()

while True :
    #Set the IIC address
    ads1115.setAddr_ADS1115(0x48)
    #Sets the gain and input voltage range.
    ads1115.setGain(ADS1115_REG_CONFIG_PGA_6_144V)
    #Get the Digital Value of Analog of selected channel
    adc0 = ads1115.readVoltage(0)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    adc1 = ads1115.readVoltage(1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    adc2 = ads1115.readVoltage(2)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    adc3 = ads1115.readVoltage(3)
    print "A0:%dmV A1:%dmV A2:%dmV A3:%dmV"%(adc0['r'],adc1['r'],adc2['r'],adc3['r'])
```

It's displaying values like

```
A0:0mv A1:1098mV A2:3286mV A3:498mV
```

But I don't know how to get actual sound value in decibel unit.

Comment: You will have to calculate it.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for reply but can you please guide me bit? How to?

Comment: Are you using the "DFRobot I2C ADS1115 16-bit ADC" with "Gravity  Analog Sound Level Meter SKU SEN0232" ? If yes or no, please provide the correct naming of the peripherals you are using.

Comment: @User404 Yes I am using these peripherals

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here:
https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_Sound_Level_Meter_SKU_SEN0232

To anwser your question:

> For this product,the decibel value is linear with the output
>   voltage.When the output voltage is 0.6V, the decibel value should be
>   30dBA. When the output voltage is 2.6V, the decibel value should be
>   130dBA. The calibration is done before leaving the factory, so you
>   don't need to calibrate it. So we can get this relation: **Decibel**
>   **Value(dBA) = Output Voltage(V) × 50**

So you need to check to which connector (A0, A1, A2 or A3) you connected your sound level meter. Take that value (which seems to be in mV) convert it to V and multiple by 50.
Or simple divide your value by 20.

Comment: I am getting this output A0:0mv A1:1098mV A2:3286mV A3:498mV. If do 1098 * 50 It's get big number :(

Comment: Also I find something similar here for DFRduino like float voltageValue,dbValue;
    voltageValue = analogRead(SoundSensorPin) / 1024.0 * VREF;
    dbValue = voltageValue * 50.0;  //convert voltage to decibel value

Comment: Your value is in mV. 1000 mV is 1 V. You also need to check to which "port" you connected your sensor so see what value you need to use.

Comment: Followed this layout https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__I2C_ADS1115_16-Bit_ADC_Module_Arduino_%26_Raspberry_Pi_Compatible__SKU__DFR0553

Comment: How did you connect your sensor to the ADC?

Comment: Sensor to ADC and ADC to Raspberry Pi. Sensor to ADC using 4 pins cables.